# Using Return and Switch in Java with the area of shapes

Tags: java, return, switch-statement

Trying to write a program that prompts a user to select circle, rectangle, or triangle, then ask for the corresponding dimensions, and then displays the area to the user.

I used some instances of returns and switches, and I think that's where I messed up.

```
package shapearea;

import java.util.Scanner; //global scanner


public class ShapeArea {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int menuOption;
       double area;

   menuOption = showMenu();
   area = processShapeOption(menuOption); 
   displayArea(area, menuOption);


}//end main

public static void displayArea(double area, int menuOption) {
   switch (menuOption) {
       case 1: System.out.printf("The area of the circle is: %.3f\n ", area);
          break; 
       case 2: System.out.printf("The area of the rectangle is: ", area);
           break;
       case 3: System.out.printf("The area of the triangle is: ", area);
           break;
   }//end switch



   }//end displayArea
   public static int showMenu() {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       int menuOption;

       System.out.println("1. circle");
       System.out.println("2. rectangle");
       System.out.println("3. triangle");
       System.out.print("enter choice:");
       menuOption = scan.nextInt();

       return menuOption;
   }//end showMenu

   public static double processShapeOption(int menuOption) {
       double area = 0;
       switch(menuOption){
           case 1: double radius = getDimension("radius");
                   area = calculateCircleArea(radius);

              break;

           case 2: double length = getDimension("length"),
                      width = getDimension("width");
                   area = areaOfRectangle(length, width);
           break;

           case 3: double base = getDimension("base"),
                      height = getDimension("height");
                   area = areaOfTriangle(base, height);

           break;


   }//end switch

   return area;     
}//end processShapeOption

public static double getDimension(String dimensionType) {
   double dimension;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the " + dimensionType + ":");
   dimension = scan.nextDouble();

   return dimension;

   }//end getDimension

   public static double calculateCircleArea(double radius) {
   double area;

   area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);

   return area;
}//end calculateCircleArea

public static double areaOfRectangle(double width, double length) {
   double area;

   area = width * length;

   return area;
}//end areaOfRectangle

public static double areaOfTriangle(double height, double base) {
   double area;

   area = .5 * base * height;

   return area;
}

}//end class
```

The part with calculating circle area works fine, but when I select rectangle it goes on to ask for triangle dimensions in addition to rectangle ones, and fails to display the area.

Edit: Added breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `break` statement after each case.

```
case 1: {
    doStuff();
    break;
}
```

Also you forgot to add

```
"%.3f\n"
```

to your printf statements for case 2 and 3

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But I still can't get the area to display for rectangle or triangle.

Comment: check your printf statements. you forgot "%.3f\n"

Comment: Thanks, the %f\n was what I was missing

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `break;` statement at the end of your each `case`. See the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double getUserInput( ) {
        double inp;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter input");
             inp=scan.nextInt();
        }while(inp<=0);
        return inp;
    }
```

use this for user input for all  positive nos.Here is complete code

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class AreaCalculator {
  static  Scanner scan;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        int counter=0;
        do{
        System.out.println("1) Triangle\n" +
"2) Square\n" +
"3) Rectangle\n" +
"4) Circle\n" +
"5) Quit\n" );
        
       // System.out.println("Enter your choice from the menu:");
 scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter your choice from the menu:");
         choice=   scan.nextInt(); 
          //  System.out.println("Enter valid choice");
        } while(choice<1||choice>5);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:System.out.println("u chose Triangle");
                System.out.println("Enter base");
         // double   base=scan.nextInt();
                double base=getUserInput();
                          System.out.println("Enter height");
        //  double  height=scan.nextInt();
                          double  height=getUserInput();
         // boolean valid=true;
      // boolean valid=    errorTrap(base, height);
       
   double area=        triangleArea(base,height);
   System.out.print("Area is "+area);
       
            continue;
            case 2:System.out.println("u chose Square.Enter Side of square");
        double side=getUserInput();
        double SquareArea=squareArea(side);
                System.out.println("Area of square is"+SquareArea);
     
            continue;
            case 3:System.out.println("u chose Rectange.Enter Length of rect");
            double length=getUserInput();
            System.out.println("Enter width of rect");
            double width=getUserInput();
         double rectArea=   rectangleArea(length,width);
         System.out.println("Area of rectangle is"+rectArea);

            continue;
            case 4:System.out.println("u chose Circle.Enter circle radius");
            double radius=getUserInput();
            double circleArea= circleArea(radius);
                System.out.println("Area of Circle is "+circleArea);
            continue;
            case 5:System.out.print("u chose exit"); scan.close();System.exit(0);
            default:System.out.print("Invalid");
            
        }
        counter++;
        }while(counter<1);
        
        scan.close();
        
    }//main
    public static double triangleArea(double base, double height){
        double area=0.5 * base *height;
        return area;
    }
    
     public static double squareArea(double side){
        double area=side*side;
        return area;
    }
     
     public static double rectangleArea(double length, double breadth){
        double area=length*breadth;
        return area;
    }
     
     public static double circleArea(double radius){
        double area=Math.PI*radius;
        return area;
    }


    public static double getUserInput( ) {
        double inp;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter input");
             inp=scan.nextInt();
        }while(inp<=0);
        return inp;
    }
}
```